# How to use Offline Speech Recognition inside the iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, ios8, speech

Does anyone knows that if "Offline speech to text" used in iOS devices?

I researched but couldn't find anything about it in documentation, so if thats not included in SDK are there any "Offline Speech Recognition" quality libraries in market?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many, here are the SDK's that I have used earlier (both are free and offline)

1. [Openears](http://www.politepix.com/openears/)
2. [Flite](https://github.com/meredian/TTSOverview-iOS/)

Comment: Am using Openears its working Thanks Bro :)

Comment: Does it support Polish language?

Comment: Not yet. However, you can create your own acoustic models in Polish language and use it instead of the existing one. Openears language list is available here: http://www.politepix.com/languages

Comment: Brother, I don't want to limit my vocabulary to some words set.
how would I use OpenEar in this case.
Please guide.

Comment: Is there any sample for Openears

Comment: https://github.com/totzyuta/OpenEars-sample

Comment: however, I recommend to use your own code. https://www.politepix.com/openears/tutorial/